# coldfusion: use string as structname

Tags: string, coldfusion, struct

I didn't find an answer to this question because I don't know if I'm expressing the problem correctly.

It's quite simple. I have this code:

```
<cfset queryAddRow(sday.morning) />
```

and I need something like this instead:

```
<cfset tday = "morning" />
<cfset queryAddRow(sday.tday) />
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Toby - you question makes me think you are wanting a new query called "tday"  added to the "sday" struct. IS that what you are saying? If so then yes - you can do it with queryNew().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming sday.morning is a query, then you can use associative array notation to reference the key dynamically:

```
struct[key]
```

where 'key' is a variable holding name of the key. In your case the code to use would be:

```
queryAddRow(sday[tday])
```

Comment: It could be that there is a query called "morning" that is a member of the "sday" struct. In which case his *queryAddRow(sday.morning)" would not throw a syntax error. It would simply add a row (appened) the query "sday.morning". There's no way to tell from the answer that syntax is incorrect.

Comment: you are right, Mark - it could be that sday is a struct holding query/ies as members. queryAddRow(sday[tday]) would still work, no?

Comment: Yes it *would* in the example above - the rest of your example would be spot on. edit your post. I'll take back my negative vote (I don't know what got into me). :)

Comment: no worries :) i edited my answer to remove part about wrong queryAddRow() syntax.

Comment: thx, this worked for queryAddRow. But now I've got an error when I use the following: <cfset querySetCell(sday[tday], "id", "test", 1) />
the error is: "There is no id column in the query object."

Comment: Toby - are you sure all queries in your sday structure do have an 'id' column? you can <cfdump var="#sday#"> to check.

Comment: Toby... do <Cfoutput>#sday[tday].columnlist#</cfoutput> ... what do you see? Is there a column named "id"?

Comment: oh, I did not create it for all queries yet, because it worked before. But now I have this error: "The row number 2 is out of bounds." what does that mean?!

Comment: Toby... we can't write it for you (ha). it means you are trying to use a "2" for the rownumber when there is likely only 1 row in the query... or something similar to that.

Comment: thx, I think I'll find that out. I can do the rest on my own!... thx again :)